# What would cause an SQLite database to be wiped?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So one of the users in my app reported that their data (saved into SQL tables) was deleted, but not their app settings (saved as shared preferences). I wrote that off to some extremely rare circumstances because no one's reported that problem before. However yesterday the same thing happened to me when I was using my app. There was a crash (not reported in Crashlytics or Play Console for some reason, and LogCat was missing everything before I connected my phone to ADB) and when I opened the app all the data saved in the SQL database was deleted while the data in shared preferences was intact.

I didn't change the app at all for months - I'm using the production version used by ~30k monthly users. My database handling code contains inserts and updates but not delete, truncate or drop statements anywhere.

What could have caused that to happen? Some corruption of the database? Why would all tables be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Any integrity failures in the Sqlite database will lead to its deletion by default. To prevent that over-ride it by passing a [DatabaseErrorHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler))